# how to capture event handlers using Proxy object

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I would like to set up a `Proxy` to capture handlers for all click event registrations.

Please consider this example:

```
let docProxy= new Proxy(document, {
   get(target, name) {
    if (name === 'getElementById') {
        console.log(arguments[0]);
    }
    return typeof target[name] == "function"
        ? target[name].bind(target)
        : target[name];
  }
});

(function(document){

     document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick=function(){ alert("click")};

})(docProxy);
```

I tried to set a proxy on `document`, so that I could get click handler for any element (in above example I want to log `function(){ alert("click")}`. What am I overlooking?

Here is the updated code. Button onclick events for both buttons (`foo`, `mybtn`) don't fire

```
let docProxy = new Proxy(document, {

    get:  (target, name, receiver) => {
        const origMethod = target[name];
        return function (...args) {
            let result = origMethod.apply( target, arguments );
            return new Proxy (result, {
                get: (obj, key, receiver) => {
                    if (key === 'addEventListener') {
                        return function() {
                            if (arguments[0] === 'click') {
                                console.log(arguments[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return typeof obj[key] == "function"
                      ? obj[key].bind(obj)
                      : obj[key];                   
                },
                set: (obj, key, value) => {
                    if (key === 'onclick') {
                        console.log(value);
                    }
                }
            });
        };
    }
});

(function(document){
   
     document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener('click', function(){ alert("click")});
     document.getElementById("mybtn").onclick=function(){ alert("click")};

})(docProxy);
```

Comment: You've made a proxy for the `document` that intercepts the `.getElementById` property access. You've not made a proxy that wraps the element that the `getElementById` call returns.

Comment: @Bergi how do I make a proxy that wraps `.getElementById` returned element?

Comment: Instead of returning `target[name].bind(target)`, return a function that calls the original method and then wraps its result in a proxy before returning it.

Comment: @Bergi is this what you mean: 
```const origMethod = target[name]; 
return function (...args) { let result = origMethod.apply( target, arguments ); 
return result; };```
how can I then get the handlers registered for clicks

Comment: You want `return new Proxy(result, {…})` there to intercept `set` assignments on `.onclick`

Comment: @Bergi worked for above click listener but `document.getElementById("mybtn")['addEventListener']('click', myfunc);` is throwing exception now

Comment: You need to intercept property accesses on the element with the `get` trap as well and return a bound/wrapped function so that native methods will be invoked on the original target, not on the proxy. You already did this on the `docProxy` in the code in your question. (And maybe you even want to capture event listeners installed using `addEventListener`).

Comment: @Bergi tnx a lot, I set the `get` trap & captured listeners that use `addEventListener` as well. But clicking buttons on the page is having no effect now

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to update it with your current code?

Comment: @Bergi pls have a look at updated code tnx

Comment: Well, you're just logging `click` events in the intercepted `addEventListener` method. You'll also need to call the original to actually install the event handler: `return obj.addEventlistener(...arguments)`

Comment: @Bergi great tnx